# Собрать несколько значений с HTML страницы

Tags: python

Никак не могу понять как притянуть тэг Времени. (эта информация есть на сайте)

Итак вот сайт 'https://3dnews.ru/news'

Вот мой код

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 
def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)    # Получим метод Response
    r.encoding = 'utf8'
    return r.text   # Вернем данные объекта text
 
soup = BeautifulSoup(get_html('https://3dnews.ru/news'), 'lxml')
head = soup.find('div', id='section-content').find_all('div', class_="cntPrevWrapper")
 
for i in head:
    link = 'https://3dnews.ru' + i.get('href')
    heads = i.find('h1').string
    date = i.find('span', class_="entry-date")
    data = {'head': heads,
            'date': date,
            'link': link}
print(data)
```

В итоге date у меня пусто.
Подскажите что не так.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в `i.get("href")` она возвращает `None` замените её на

```
i.find("a", class_ = "entry-header").get("href")
```

Comment: С ссылкой нет проблем, она вытягивается корректно, а вот дата публикации (переменная date) пустая. Именно там проблема.